# Render Image on the Bootstrap card component

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap card class, which has Image on the top with a Title. I would like to render/display image into bootstrap card-img-class on a fly from the DOM element by invoking javascript function. My images are being saved in the database like contents through the markdown editor. There may be multiple images being referenced in the markdown editor however card-img-class should have first image from the DOM elements.

```
 class="col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 9px !important">
<div class="card h-100 w-80">
   **<img class="card-img-top" src="getCardImage()" alt="Card Image Top">**
   <div class="card-body rounded-bottom">
       <div class="Heading">
           <a href="@($"/Tech/{(Model.Slug == UrlHelpers.HomePageSlug ? "" : Model.Slug)}")">@Model.Title</a>
       </div>
       <hr />
       <div class="main-content">
           <p class="card-text text-justify">
               <markd`enter code here`own markdown="Description" />
           </p>
           <p class="readMore">
               <a href="@($"/Tech/{(Model.Slug == UrlHelpers.HomePageSlug ? "" : Model.Slug)}")">Read More>> </a>
           </p>
       </div>
```

My javascript code follow:-

```
(function() {
    var getCardImage = function () {
        var Image = document.querySelectorAll("p img:nth-child(0)");        
        return Image;
    };
    getCardImage();
})();
```

HTML being displayed in the browser:

```
 <p>
         <img alt="" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSvtIcyZ6HwrUNB2r-YUpWbSfEPkadb0KtuBSvGjKsjT7Ex7VyFw">
        </p>   
    <p>
      .card-img-top places an image to the top of the card. With .card-text,  
    text   can be added to the card. Text within .card-text can also be   
      styled with the standard HTML tags
</p>
    <p>
    <img alt="" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/creativetim_bucket/products/19/original/opt_rcc_thumbnail.jpg?1459863435">
    </p.
```